# Summing specific values in a joined list

Tags: google-sheets

I am having some difficulties summing up some values in Google Sheets.  In my spreadsheet, from multiple other tabs, values and bonuses are combined into one cell (Cell B1 in this example).  The format of each "unit" of data is Name,5%xxx (Where "Name" is the name of the item, "5%" represents the sum I want to add, mostly always a percentage, and "xxx" separates one unit from the next).  As you can see in cell B1, there are two instances where "Parkour" receives a bonus to sum up (from different sources).

|  | Parkour,5%xxxParkour (Subskill: Sense of Balance),10%xxxParkour,2%xxx |
| --- | --- |
| Parkour | 0.07 |
| Parkour (Subskill: Sense of Balance) |  |
| H2H Combat: Parkour |  |

The formula in cell B2 is:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VALUE(MID(FILTER(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,filter(B$1,regexmatch(B$1,$A2)=TRUE)),"xxx"),SEARCH($A2,SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,filter(B$1,regexmatch(B$1,$A2)=TRUE)),"xxx"))),len($A2)+2,1000)),""))),"")
```

(Dragged down through the rest of the list) (Could not figure out how to make the formula "in line" on the question.)

Expected Results:

B2 = .07 (Working)

B3 = .1 (**Not working**)

B4 = Blank (Working)

The goal of the formula is to look into cell B1, and split everything out by "xxx".  Then, filter the array of items with only exact matches with the line item in column A, then split again by the comma and add up those values.  It worked for the first line item, but not the second.  (Unsure why, but I strongly believe it has something to do with the parenthesis.  When I removed the parenthesis from the name in Column A (and adjusted cell B1 to not have parenthesis), it worked.  However, given the structure of the data, parenthesis are required, and I need to find a way for it to work with them.)

When I removed the `IFERROR` wrap around it in cell B3, I get this error note:

> Function SUM parameter 1 expects number values. But " is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find useful combining SPLIT with QUERY like this. It will group names and sum percentages:

```
=QUERY(INDEX (IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(INDEX(SPLIT(B1:B100,"xxx"))),","))),"SELECT Col1,SUM(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1")
```

[image]

PS: invented a couple of extra line

---

### UPDATE

I've thought you had another goal, try this formula. Having the previous chart generated by QUERY, I used VLOOKUP to match first column and return second one:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR (VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY(INDEX (SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(B1,"xxx")),",")),"SELECT Col1,SUM(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"),2,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: I put that formula in column B next to Parkour, and got a circular error.  (The B1:B100 part caused that, as the item will only be in cell B1.).  When I changed that from B1:B100 to just B1, it created a separate table with names in column B, and sums in column C.  I'm trying to get just the sums into column B (The list in column A is static).

Comment: See the update if it fits your needs

Comment: WORKS!  LOVE IT!  And, it seems to run a bit faster than the old way!  Not in the original question, but I'm a little confused by the output of the answer.  I don't think I'd seen this behavior before without using ARRAYFORMULA.  (The "VLOOKUP(A2:A," part, specifically...).

Comment: Using INDEX only with its first parameter is almost the same as using ARRAYFORMULA. I sometimes prefer it to have a shorter formula, but basically it's the same 